# Find a value in a string and return the text in the adjacent cell in Excell

Tags: excel, search, find, match

I have a list of numbers in column A. I am trying to search the strings of data in `E:E` for an exact match and return the corresponding value to the right of the cell found, or just return the last 8 of the string my match found since I can concatenate the value to the end.

I have tried the formula `<=RIGHT(FIND(A2,E:E),14)>` with no luck.

`H5=VLOOKUP(A3,E:F,2,0)` but `VLOOKUP` will not search a "string" of text to find a match.

So I am trying to find `A2:8255572463`.

In `E:E`

```
E2:8255572463;8255572464;8255572465
E3:8255572463;8255572464;8255572465
```

I am trying to Search for the Value of A2 in E:E and return the value in the cell to the right (F) of the Cell in E:E that the data was found  into column B .

Comment: so you're looking for: a number "n" .. and if you find it .. you want to display what ?  just "n" ??

Answer (score 0):

If you're just trying to pull the value in column A if you find it in the list .. it's probably easier to show the value from A .. and not try to rip it out of the string .. you've already confirmed it's there ;)

Try this in cell B2 ..

```
=IF(ISERROR(FIND(CONCATENATE(";",$A2,";"),CONCATENATE(";",E2,";"))), "", A2)
```